# go container build (arm) with CGO timeout with net/http: TLS handshake timeout

Tags: go, arm, cgo, go-get, cross-build

I have a project using `go mod` and `CGO` that has a relatively large dependency tree.

Building natively (`GOOS=linux`, `GOARCH=amd64`) works fine.
Building in a CI (on my own runner) using my custom build container (several architectures, including `arm`) works mostly ok, though I sometimes get "hangs" while `go get`ting deps.

Using the same build image to locally build for `arm` (I need to use a container because of `CGO` and the corresponding arch-dependent C-toolchain) now gives me the following errors (one example of many):

```
go: downloading github.com/go-co-op/gocron v1.9.0
scheduler/scheduler.go:7:2: github.com/go-co-op/gocron@v1.9.0: Get "https://goproxy.io/github.com/go-co-op/gocron/@v/v1.9.0.zip": net/http: TLS handshake timeout
```

However, I can see (with `btop`) that just before this error `qemu-arm` was very busy (800 CPU%) running `go` related build tasks (in fact a `go mod tidy` process).

My guess is that this is due to no suitable binary for `arm` for particular modules being found, so it will just build them on-the-fly.

So I suspect that the time for the respective module builds from source is counted by `go get` as a normal "go get from http", which leads to the observed timeout.

Consequently this would mean I could solve the issue if I would be able to increase the timeout value for `go get`, but I haven't found any info on that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your ISP may have restrictions on accessing https://goproxy.io address. You must use a proxy

set proxy in terminal like:

```
export https_proxy=127.0.0.1:1080
```

Comment: The CI host is running inside the LAN, so from ISP's perspective there's no difference between my local (dev) host and the gitlab-runner (just another server in my LAN). The timeouts consistently happen only on `arm` builds, which involve heavier compile tasks than my native arch.